# How to get Value from Gtk Scale / Range widget?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I am making my first ever C# project using monodevelop stetic gui creator. I have a few buttons, a TextView object and some Vertical and Horizontal Scaling widgets. These are all Gtk (or Gtk#, or Gtk+??) Widgets, not sure which. And I REALLY can't understand the documentation - not even sure which documentation I should be reading.

I would like to get a value from the Scale widgets, which are a subclass of Gtk.Range, which handles anything that involves scrolling.

I would also like to get a better understanding of what Gtk is and any good sources of knowledge on the subject. So far all I have been able to do is copy [these tutorials](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Building_a_simple_application_using_the_Stetic_GUI_Designer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gtk# is the C# wrapper around GTK+ 2.x (GTK+ 3.x port is in progress). Yes, the plus "+" is part of the name even if you'll find GTK+ referenced as GTK or gtk most of the time. The best documentation can be found on the Gtk website:

http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php

Gtk# converts most of the functions to CamelCase methods (stripping the gtk_xxx_ prefix because a method already implies a class); setters and getters to properties and signals to events. It is quite easy after the first moments of pure terror when nothing works.

For example, lets check how to get a value from a `Gtk.Range`. We start from the Gtk+ 2 documentation about `GtkRange`:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkRange.html#gtk-range-get-value

`gtk_range_get_value` seems to be the best candidate and it is a getter function that takes a `GtkRange` "object" as first argument (this is a pointer to a struct in plain C but let's call it object anyway because that what we get in Gtk#). Gtk# usually makes this an instance property getter, so let's try

```
Gtk.Range yourRange = /* your code to get or create the range */;
COnsole.WriteLine(yourRange.Value);
```

and it works. :D